# jQuery - How to removeProp on checkbox change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, required, prop

I have checkbox that I'm using to toggle whether an input field is "required" using jQuery. This is part of Foundation Abide validation. So, at the end of the input field it needs to add/remove the word "required".

The box is checked by default. When the user unchecks the box it adds "required" to the input as it should (else if). However, if you recheck the box, the "removeProp" doesn't remove "required". What am I doing wrong on this? I've tried both prop and attr functions with the same result.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="billing" checked>

<input type="text" id="b_name" pattern="alpha" required>


$('#billing').change(function() {

    // Same as Shipping Address
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#b_name').removeProp('required');
    }
    else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#b_name').prop('required', true);
    }

  });
```

Comment: just set it to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#billing').change(function() {

    // Same as Shipping Address
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#b_name').prop('required', false);
    }
    else {
      $('#b_name').prop('required', true);
    }

  });
```

Comment: That worked. Could have sworn that I tried that earlier. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Got wait the designated minimum time before it will let me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see the behavior there. Once it removes the property it is not adding the property back.

You can see the same case mentioned at **[Jquery docs for .removeProp()](http://api.jquery.com/removeprop/)**.

As it says -

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

So you can set it to false and true on check and uncheck rather than removing the property completly

```js
$('#billing').change(function() {

    // Same as Shipping Address
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#b_name').prop('required', false);
    }
    else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#b_name').prop('required', true);
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="billing" checked>

<input type="text" id="b_name" pattern="alpha" required>
```